# Are there problems upgrading to 64-bit Windows 7 on a SSD?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ssd

I have a Dell M4400 with 32-bit Windows 7 and a solid state disk.  Will I run into any problems installing 64-bit Windows 7 on the SSD?  Should I reformat the drive?  Any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading from 32-bit windows to Windows 7 64-bit, the Windows installer requires you to use the *Custom* installation option--*Upgrade* will not be available.  The *Custom* install will require you to reinstall your applications.  Given this, I would recommend backing up your files and have the Windows installer format the drive during the install.

Links for further information are below:

- [32-bit and 64-bit Windows: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions)
- [Installing and reinstalling Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Installing-and-reinstalling-Windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any issues using a 64-bit OS instead of a 32-bit OS, as far as the SSD is concerned. It may, as you mention, be worth completely wiping the SSD (doing a [secure erase](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2738/11)) before installing the new OS. This is because it "resets" the SSD and restores all free space, which is  important for the performance of the drive.

Comment: Actually, doing a secure erase is quite bad for the drive, as it basically decreases the health of every cell of the drive. Like defragmenting an SSD drive, except a lot worse.

Comment: @hello71 No, overall, it should be better for the drive (as well as performance). In the long run, a secure erase will help minimise the write amplification ratio, which means less “waste” is written to the SSD, which should help towards a longer lifetime. Plus, performance will be [significantly better](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2738/13). Of course, wiping the entire SSD will erase every cell (so, for MLC, using up 1 out of each cell’s ~10,000 lifetime writes), so you wouldn’t do this often. Also, if TRIM has been in use, then a secure erase may not yield a huge improvement.